# Is fopen() guaranteed to return same value for same path value?

Tags: c++, fopen

Given the same `path` argument to `FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)`, is `fopen()` guaranteed to return the same `FILE*` value?

E.g., is the output of the following code guaranteed to always be two pointers of the same value?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int foo( FILE* fp )
{
  std::cout << fp << std::endl;
  fclose(fp);
  fp = fopen( "foo.txt", "w+" );
  std::cout << fp << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char* arv[] )
{
  FILE* fp = fopen( "foo.txt", "a" );
  fwrite( "hello", 5, 1, fp );
  foo( fp );
  fwrite( "goodbye", 7, 1, fp );
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

I.e. I'm wondering if `foo()`'s manipulation of its local `fp` is invalidating `main()`'s. But this code, compiled, always outputs the same `FILE*` value twice, implying `main()`'s is still valid, even if `foo()` is working on a local copy instead of a reference.

For some context, this is a simplification of a bug I'm chasing at work: the equivalent of the second `fwrite()` above sometimes returns `0`, and I'm trying to track down why. It looks like `fwrite()`'s error reporting is limited to `ferror()` and `feof()`, but the above sample code, compiled, always outputs the same pointer value twice, implying the code is okay, and I'm left unclear why either the `ferror()` or `feof()` conditions would be hit.

Comment: Your fp is closed. The new fp isn't visible in main.

Comment: ...and to answer the question, no. fopen returns a pointer to an internal structure. Which one the system uses is not under user control--it might reuse the same one (even for different files), or it might not.

Comment: The returned `FILE*` can be different. Depending on the implementation you *may* get the same address from `fopen()` as the previous `fclose()` argument. However, there is zero guarantee.

Comment: The value returned by fopen() doesn't identify the file, it points to a FILE structure, which ill be different for each call to fopen() - so no.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - would it be correct to say, then, that if `foo()`'s `fopen()` returned the same value as `main()`'s `fp` (and pointed to a valid, writable file), then the second `fwrite()` in `main()` ought not fail?

Comment: It can't return the same pointer, because doing things like seeks or closes on the pointer  must differ in their behaviour.

Comment: I guess in theory `fopen` could allocate the memory that `fclose` just freed and you would end up with a new `FILE` object at the same address as the old one, but that seems very unlikely.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - I would have expected the same, but you'll note the code above prints the value of `fp` before and after the `fclose()` and `fopen()` and on my Linux box, those values are the same. I take your point, though: `main()` is inappropriately expecting its pointer to be valid/unchanged after calling `foo()`, but let me know if you know why the compiled code outputs the same pointer value twice, against expectation; I'm curious.

Comment: @MilesBudnek - Agreed it should be unlikely, however on my Linux box, the compiled code consistently does output the same value twice. Head scratcher.

Comment: Calling fopen doesn't give you a unique pointer if you called fclose on it prior to another call to fopen.

Comment: I guess if there are no other allocations around the same time, then (at least with glibc), the `free` in `fclose` will leave a hole that's just perfect for the following `malloc` in `fopen` to use.  [Add another `fopen` call](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3ebd5666c0d9455) and it won't fit so well.

Comment: No. It returns different value. not same.

Comment: It certainly ***can*** return the same value, but it’s a new object, and more importantly will start out with e.g. the current `fpos()` set to the start of the file (unless you open it in append mode). And it certainly isn’t guaranteed to. This is a coding error, whichever way you look at it.